# angular directive multiple selectors and @HostListener, @HostBinding

Tags: angular

This article describes how to implement multiple selector in a same single directive:

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3367-matching-multiple-selectors-on-the-same-element-creates-a-single-directive-instance-in-angular-5-0-0.htm

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[everySecond] , [everyTwoSeconds]",
    outputs: [
        "everySecond",
        "everyTwoSeconds"
    ]
})
export class PingDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   @HostListener('mouseleave') mouseleave(e:Event){}
   @HostBinding('background-color') backgroundColor: string;
}
```

but when I denfine `@HostListener` or `@HostBinding` ,both are for same directive `PingDirective`.

Can you define it separately? To the following structure, you can listen to different span events and define css, `everySecond` or `everyTwoSeconds`.

```
<span everySecond> 
 everySecond 
 <span everyTwoSeconds>
 everyTwoSeconds
 </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can define another input i.e atype='events' or atype='css'.

Based on input type, you can handle click events and define CSS properties.

```
<span everySecond="true" atype="events"> 
 everySecond 
 <span everyTwoSeconds atype="css">
 everyTwoSeconds
 </span>
</span>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwobuk

Comment: thank! it's work.But, how to set their css separately, like by `Renderer2`.

Comment: `constructor(private renderer: Renderer2)` is build both `everySecond` and `everyTwoSeconds`,can be defined individually?

Comment: sorry, I mean like this `if (this.everySecond){
       one = this.renderer;
     }else if(this.everytwoSecond){ two = this.renderer;}`, when I click `everySecond`,can I to set css for `this.one` or `this.two` or both?

Comment: You don't need any condition. Straight away access this.elementRef.nativeElement will give access to the particular DOM Element. Refer stackblitz

Comment: updated at `ping.directive.ts` line 20 : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdwzy2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fping.directive.ts

Comment: We can't achieve this. may be you can try this.el.nativeElement.parentNode;

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Just define a `@Input` property for every selector of your directive:

```
export class PingDirective {
   @Input() everySecond: boolean;
   @Input() everyTwoSeconds: boolean;

   ngOnInit() {
     if (this.everySecond) console.log('every second!');
   }
}
```

This works because Angular allows you to define [Input properties](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#pass-values-into-the-directive-with-an-input-data-binding) for your directives. The name of input property can also be the same of your selector (in this way you can pass data to your directive, for example `[timeout]="1"` for a directive with `selector: '[timeout]'`).

With the above code, you are saying to Angular that you expect two `Input` s for your directive, they can be both present (and both variable would be true), can be only one present, but **at least one** should be present, otherwise the `@Directive` selector won't match it

Comment: Can you give me more details?

Comment: Obviously you'll be able to define your events with `if (this.everySecond)` and `if (this.everyTwoSeconds)`

Comment: what is about the `boolean` var form `@Input() everySecond` and `@Input() everyTwoSecond`? How does it work?

Comment: `<span [everySecond]>` puts `everySecond` to true

Comment: When do I need to give it true or false?How do I listener their events separately, and define css?