# Knowing which Selector was used in the template

Tags: angular

Let's say I have the following directive :

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'button[my-button], button[my-button-outline]',
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() color = 'primary';

  @HostBinding('class')
  public get colorClass(): string {
    return `btn btn-${this.color}`;
  }
}
```

I would like to assign a different class depending on if I used `my-button` or `my-button-outline`

Is this behavior possible in Angular 12 ?

There is a similar question, but without solution :
[Multiple directive selectors - find which selector was used in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390879/multiple-directive-selectors-find-which-selector-was-used-in-template)

Comment: Something like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-689xbh?file=src/app/testi.directive.ts

Comment: yeah, that looks like it works. I hoped a solution more "sugary" but that's looks like it s enough for me, thanks